# Mysterious symbol which prevents js minification or may be error cause when compiling javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs

Resently I was just playing with wonderful [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) when I noticed some strange symbol which gives me minification errors. It looks strange to me because I can't select or copy it and it is not any special character. At least I know (LF,CR,Tab or space).

In notepad++ it looks like this:

[image]

If I put cursor at the beggining of line 95 and press backspace picture becomes like this:
[image]

I can delete it though. But I am curiuos. On the other hand I'd rather remove it by means of regex so to be sure these won't spoil my js files. So what is this and how can I find it and remove with regex or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Unicode [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

The Uglifier may not be expecting BOM formatted files and it's treating the BOM as a character.

Comment: Actuall in my Visual Studio I am ussually using utf-8 without signature (codepage 65001). But yes you are right this is have to be some remains of BOM. I just applied option `UTF-8 without BOM` to responsible files and these came away. Thanks.

Comment: I faced a typical 'headers already sent' PHP error that was caused by class files being saved with BOM, and when the classes were being included the "extra" character would show up even if nothing else in the entire project was outputting anything.